# How can I record a video of the Android Emulator running?

Tags: android, youtube, android-emulator, video-capture

What's the best way to record a video showing things running on the Android Emulator? I want to record little demo videos of stuff running so I can put it on YouTube.

I'm running the emulator on either Windows or a Mac.

Comment: On Windows you can try Fraps. If that doesn't work, something like Camtasia might do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CamStudio. It's free and doesn't include any markings on the output.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac you can capture the screen using QuickTime. You should be able to crop the video afterwards in iMovie.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it all in one easy step you can use Jing ( http://www.jingproject.com/ ). It records and subsequently uploads it to their webspace, all for free.

Answer (score 0):

[HyperCam](http://download.cnet.com/HyperCam/3000-13633_4-10004511.html?tag=mncol) has plently of features that you can use to create your protfolio of work on YouTube. It's free to try but for this there is a watermark icon on all videos you make, you can buy the full version if you want to and the watermark will be removed.

You should be fine with the free edition.